# HtmlAgilityPack SelectSingleNode() to the third instance of an h3 heading

Tags: html, xpath, selectsinglenode, selectnodes

Under the Chrome Browser, I have Exported the Html from one Bookmarks-bar folder containing 4 subfolders (each with its respective Html h3 heading names).  Then, in the exported Html code itself, I want to skip over the first 2 cosmetic (not relevant) h3 headings, and then work on the remaining third, fourth, fifth and sixth parent h3 headings, each containing 20+ `//a[@href]` links respectively.

I know in advance that the third h3 text says "Locomotive Train Engine By Number".  So, I want to extract its node and text first.  I tried both of these and they failed:

```
Dim node3LocomotiveByNumber As HtmlNode = DPL_Bookmark_Html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[3])")
node3LocomotiveByNumber = DPL_Bookmark_Html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h3[3]/text()")
writeNGDTextOut.WriteLine(node3LocomotiveByNumber.InnerText)
```

Over the course of two whole days, I found 3-4 total simplistic "//h3" examples.  But NONE included the [3] index.  Painfully, I need your help.  What could be wrong? I'm out of ideas.

Continuing, I have tried and used this code for links:

```
For Each eaLink As HtmlNode In DPL_Bookmark_Html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
```

If so, once I can get the simple SelectSingleNode h3-text code to work, I can then use each of these four loops like this, right?

```
For Each eaLink As HtmlNode In DPL_Bookmark_Html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[3]/a[@href]")
For Each eaLink As HtmlNode In DPL_Bookmark_Html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[4]/a[@href]")
For Each eaLink As HtmlNode In DPL_Bookmark_Html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[5]/a[@href]")
For Each eaLink As HtmlNode In DPL_Bookmark_Html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h3[6]/a[@href]")
```

Am I close?  In the absense of a strong example, I'm stumped.

Comment: If you have an XPath expression `exp` returning items and you want the third item use `(exp)[3]`  and not `exp[3]` so in your case `(//h3)[3]`.

Comment: Further to @MartinHonnen's point, keep in mind that a predicate (such as `[3]`) in a path expression applies to _the preceding step_. Since the shorthand form `//h3[3]` is equivalent to `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::h3[3]` (see <https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev>), it returns the set of `h3` elements which are the third `h3` child of their parent elements (i.e. the same set as `//h3[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=2]`). Whereas with parentheses, `(//h3)` returns the set of all `h3` elements in the document, and any predicate applies to _that entire set_.